# Deleting an accepted answer requires more clicks than neccesary

Tags: feature-request, usability

I deleted an answer I posted to one of my own questions after it turned out to be incorrect.  I first got an error saying I couldn't delete an accepted answer.  However once I unaccepted it, I was able to delete it without problem.  Could the error be changed to a confirmation message instead that had an unaccept and delete option?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable request to me